# C Data Types Concept

Tags: c

Please explain this:

```
int main()
{   
    float f = 0.7;
    if(f<0.7)
        printf("Y");
    else
        printf("N");
    return 0;
}
```

Output: Y

But, for this code

```
int main()
{
    float f = 0.8;
    if(f<0.8) 
        printf("Y");
    else   
        printf("N");
    return 0;
}
```

Output is N.
What causes such difference in the output? Please try to explain in detail. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Don't mix floats and doubles.

Comment: @juanchopanza Strictly speaking that is not correct duplicate. That answer deals with decimal to binary issues, where as this question asks about precision issues with different data types.

Comment: I think its Ok now.

Comment: @user694733 - The OP uses the same datatype. They just assured it's more of a dupe now.

Comment: @StoryTeller Those constants are `double`.

Comment: @user694733 - And are representable in floats as well. This won't even elicit a narrowing conversion error.

Comment: Tell me the logic folks.

Comment: @ShwetankBhardwaj - Read the duplicate buddy. There's no explaining this without going off the deep end about floating point representation.

Comment: @ShwetankBhardwaj The problem is that you cannot store the number 0.7 in a floating point variable, so the system rounds this to the nearest value that it can store. And the nearest value for a double is not the same as for a float.

Comment: @MrLister - This isn't about representation, this is about constants being made to fit in the the data type they are assigned to. Despite `0.8` being a double constant, it can be stored in a float without warning just the same. Compilers are going to pick the closest float, not just transform an actual double. Hence, not even a warning.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate. Linked question is about mixing decimal and floating point numbers. This is about mixing different representations of floating point numbers.

Comment: @rcgldr but binary representation really doesn't matter here. The question is basically why `x < x` is sometimes `true` sometimes `false`.

Comment: @el.pescado - I deleted my prior comment, missed an edit, reposting in a bit.

Comment: The comparison is promoted to double. Due to the way floats and doubles are stored in memory, 0.7f (float) is less than 0.7 (double), but 0.8f (float) is greater than 0.8 (double). The approximate values are: 0.7f ~= 0.699999988, 07. ~= 6.9999999999999996, 0.8f ~= 0.800000012, 0.8 ~= 8.0000000000000004 ,

Comment: Use float a = 0.7f; if( a < 0.7f); Since you are comparing float variables, try to use **f** notation for float. by default it is double.