# Why this program is printing "Yes" as output?

Tags: c++

I was just playing around with data types and landed on this dilemma.
Can anyone here explain me the reason

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    float a= 0.7;
    if(a < 0.7)
        cout<<"Yes";
    else
        cout<<"No";
    return 0;
}
```

I know it is because automatically 0.7 as a literal will be of double.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    float a= 0.8;
    if(a < 0.8)
    cout<<"Yes";
    else
    cout<<"No";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because 0.7 cannot be represented exactly as a binary floating point number.

Comment: And what *is* your "dilemma"? What is the problem with the code you show? What is the actual and expected output? Please put all that *in the body of the question*, the title should just be a short summary of the question in the body. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7011184/995714 https://stackoverflow.com/q/6883306/995714 https://stackoverflow.com/q/16698198/995714

Comment: Of course, one question may be that it assigned 0.7 to a variable and then compared the variable to 0.7, so shouldn't they be equal? And the answer is "no", because the 0.7 is converted from `double` to `float` by the assignment to the variable, losing some precision in the process, and converted back from `float` to `double` for the comparison, but the values are no longer equal.

Comment: So the question might not be an exact duplicate, due to the niggle of comparing the variable to the value that was just assigned to it.

Comment: `float a = 0.7` == 0.699999988, but `auto b = 0.7` == 0.69999999999999996 because it is treated as double. (The second duplicate reference explains this)

Comment: Try changing the test to `if(a == 0.7f)` and it should print "Yes".

Comment: Seriously? This *exact* same question was already asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45932836/c-data-types-concept#comment78823945_45932836

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0.7` has no exact representation as `float`. The approximate `float` is a bit less than the `double` representation of `0.7` (which is the default interpretation when use as a constant in the `if` statement) .

For more details on that, see the question linked for duplicate or the countless variations in the comments.